# Android, Google Sign In and Firebase authentication testing

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, android-testing, google-signin

I am working on an app that requires the user to log in via Google and then gets logged in to a Firebase user account. The authentication part is more or less copy pasted from this Firebase [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin).

I want to write some automated tests for my app that can run both locally on my emulator, and on a Jenkins server. I have an authentication activity that has 2 states (with one different layout each) : logged in or out, and I want to be able to test both.

However, since the app always starts with the user logged out, I need to be able to make a test go through, or around, the authentication process, so that I can test the logged in state.

Unfortunately, once the user presses the `Sign In` button (part of my app), the Google API login activity starts. In order to log in, I would need to write a test that can press the right buttons and maybe enter some Google username and password correctly. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the code of this Google activity and I don't know how to access its controls and text fields through a test...

Does anybody know how to do this ? Maybe there is a way to go around the authentication process for testing purposes ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can maybe use a tool like the new Espresso Recorder to inspect the Google sign-in page?